# Understanding DataBinding in Windows Phone Develpment

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-8, viewmodellocator

I'm having a little trouble understanding Data Binding.
I am trying to learn `Windows Phone 8` Development.

I am trying to understand some sample code here.

In the `MainPage.xaml` he defines the `DataContext`:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    <Binding Path = "Master"
             Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
```

`Locator` is a `ViewModelLocator` defined as `Resource` in `App.xaml`  and
`Master` is a public property of type `MasterViewModel`.

So I thought this means you have now access to the properties of the `MasterViewModel` class.
And you have. But on the same page he binds to properties that are not in `MasterViewModel`, but in a totally different `ViewModel`:

```
Text="{Binding Model.FirstName}"
```

`Model` is a property in a different `ViewModel`.

So how can he access it? He did not overrde the `DataContext` somewhere as far as I can see.
What am I missing?

I didn't post a lot of code, because I think I just don't understand data binding yet and the answer will be obvious to you. I can show you more code if needed, it's sample code from Laurent Ibugnion.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
In his video he says he can use the dataBinding because in the DataTemplate the DataContext is set to a different ViewModel...but I can't see where he sets this viewModel:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FriendItemTemplate">
        <Grid Width="480"
              Height="112"
              Margin="0"
              Background="#FF5E0000">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="124" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Fill="#FF0B3100"
                       Stroke="Black"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       Visibility="{Binding OlderThanMeIndicatorVisibility, Mode=OneWay}" />

            <Image Source="{Binding Model.PictureUri}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Margin="24,6,0,0" Height="100" />

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Margin="12,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="{Binding Model.FirstName}"
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}"
                               Margin="0" />

                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text=" "
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}"
                               Margin="0" />

                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="{Binding Model.LastName}"
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}"
                               Margin="0" />
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="{Binding Model.DateOfBirth}"
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

EDIT: SOLVED
i finally found it,

```
ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FriendItemTemplate}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFriend, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your assumptions seem to be correct. There must be a DataContext set somewhere. Maybe in code behind? Or does your Locator have a property called Model?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the ViewModelLocator does not have a Model property, thats why I dont understand it. The Model property is in a class called FriedViewModel.

Comment: The sample code can be found here http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/resources/Samples/MIX11-DeepDiveMvvm-Samples.zip  its the    01 JsonDemo - After wiring up    project for windowsPhone

Answer (score 1):

The code you show us is an ItemTemplate as a ressource. The data is bound in the listbox. In there you bind to the SelectedFriend.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FriendItemTemplate}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFriend, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The DataContext property is used, when no other data binding is applied.